# Overall coverage is set to 0% while coverage on Unit tests is 37%

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jacoco, sonarqube-scan, jacoco-maven-plugin

We have maven based project, and runs on jenkins integrated with SonarQube which reports coverage using jacoco plugin.

Overall Coverage is showing 0% while coverage on tests is 37%.

Can anyone help? Let me know if you need anymore details?

SonarQube version = 5.6.6

Comment: What version of SonarQube are you using?

Comment: 5.6.6 is version of my sonarqube

Comment: please [edit] that into your question. People who want to answer don't always read comment threads.